# Slugify and PIL images not working simultaneously inside Django Model Save method

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library, slugify

**models.py**

```
def rand_slug():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(6))

class Product(models.Model):
    """
    The Product table contining all product items.
    """
  
    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=("title"),
        help_text=("Required"),
        max_length=255,
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name=("image"),
        help_text=("Upload a product image"),
        upload_to="rental_equipments",
        default="default-equipment.jpg",
    )
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=("description"), help_text=("Add a detailed description"), blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(verbose_name=("Model"), max_length=25,null=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField(verbose_name=("Serial Number"),null=True, max_length=25)
    warrenty = models.DateField(verbose_name=("Warrenty Upto"),null=True, max_length=25)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name=("Post Publically"),
        help_text=("---Remove tick mark and save for later"),
        default=True,
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(("Created at"), auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(("Updated at"), auto_now=True)
    posted_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posted_by", on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        img=img.resize((640,480))
        img.save(self.image.path)
        
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(rand_slug() + "-" + self.title)
```

in my Save method, when I use image-resize without slugify function, it works perfectly, similarly slugify without image resize also works fine.. why do both work at the same time? please help!! this problem haunting me for hours!

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(rand_slug() + "-" + self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        img=img.resize((640,480))
        img.save(self.image.path)
```